# Override comments.php template with plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, templates, comments, comments-template

How can I override default theme/WP Core comments.php template with my own in the plugin? I searched for different solutions, but they don't work for me.

Or how to hook to the end of any post (even custom post type) to display my custom comments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The `comments_template` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comments_template/):

```
add_filter( 'comments_template', function ( $template ) {
    return '/absolute/path/to/your/comments.php';
});
```

Comment: Great! It's what I want. I'll mark it as answer asap